# remix.run Visitors getting error "cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'handle')"

Tags: react-router, remix, remix.run

some user of my Remix Application getting this error and i can't reproduce it and neither know how to fix it. Happily some users send me a screenshot of it.

At first i need to say i have defined a CatchBoundary and a ErrorBoundary in the root of my application which should send me the error via email if something happens but it doesn't. So i think this error happens before it get initialised.

The Stack Trace says:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'handle') 
   at https://.../build/_shared/chunk-XTT3FRU5.js:24:2309
   Array.map (<anonymous>)....
```

PS: Sorry for not typing the whole stacktrace, i just got it via screenshot so i have to type it.

I checked that code inside the minified script and found this part, which seems to initialise the routes:

```
function ee() {
  let { routeModules: e } = w();
  return fe().map((r) => ({
    id: r.id,
    pathname: r.pathname,
    params: r.params,
    data: r.data,
    handle: e[r.id].handle,
  }));
}
```

I only have 2 routes where i export a handle, one to implement an external script and one where i set dynamic links. Both depending on the remix-utils package, i guess. As i said i can't reproduce the error by myself, i even used "BrowserStack" to test the live application in different browser.

Did anybody else have this error or an idea what could be the reason of getting it?